# Как вызвать приложение у пользователя на рабочем столе от службы в Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi-7, службы

Пишу службу на Delphi 7.

Мне нужно чтобы у пользователя по определённому событию появлялось окно программы (отдельной - то есть не службы) то есть другого форм-приложения так же написанного на Delphi.
Можно ли это как то сделать и если да то как? Я так понимаю нужно использовать ShellApi в uses?
Касаемо логина и пароля пользователя от имени которого нужно запустить стороннюю программу - они известны с этим проблем нет.

Ещё поясню что службу я пишу в настройках указав что она не имеет визуального интерфейса, поэтому запускать служба будет именно отдельный exe-файл.

Comment: Пожалуйста не задавайте сразу несколько разных вопросов. Стоит задать их отдельными вопросами (вы можете получить их текст посмотрев историю правок этого вопроса)

Comment: Я понял. Извнините, не знал, учту в будущем. Я просто новенький.